# horizontal scroll for css grid-layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I need to have different layouts for a dashboard. I need only horizontal scroll for layout-container if the items exceed to fit in a visible viewport. I came across a layout with the following requirements.

[image: This is the layout I required]

I have created the layout style using CSS-flexbox, but could not get the horizontal scroll, got the vertical scroll only.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.item {
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}
.item1 {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item1">4</div>
  <div class="item item2">5</div>
  <div class="item item3">6</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/TechnoGeek/pen/GdZodo

So, I thought, CSS grid can help with this. So I tried something but did not understand how to get it.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-row: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  /*   grid-auto-flow: column; */
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item1">4</div>
  <div class="item item2">5</div>
  <div class="item item3">6</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/TechnoGeek/pen/BxKoaG

In the grid layout, items are shrinking to fit within the layout.

The number of items inside the container is dynamic. Irrespective of the item count the layout must maintain the structure for each visible group.

Can someone help how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try overflow-x:scroll...may it helps

Comment: it is not working, can you check the code pens once?

Comment: for horizontal scroll,you need to add any specific width to the parent div.

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela, I have inserted code snippets in the question. I have added what you said. It is no use. I guess you are addressing container with `display: block`  but I am using `display: flex or grid;` If I did not understand what you said, can you send the code snippet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a satisfactory answer using CSS Grid layout.

> In the grid layout, items are shrinking to fit within the layout.

I have defined the grid lines using `fr` in my question that is why the items are shrinking. Now I have used `%` because I want the cell items to flow out of visible area to produce scroll if needed.

and `span` keyword in defining grid cell areas helped a lot for auto placement of grid cells.

> From MDN:   `span && [ <integer> || <custom-ident> ]`
>
> Contributes a grid span to the grid item’s placement such that the corresponding edge of the grid item’s grid area is n lines from the opposite edge.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50%);
  /*grid-gap: 5px;*/
  grid-auto-columns: 50%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid;
  grid-area: span 1 / span 1;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: span 1/ span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item1">4</div>
  <div class="item item2">5</div>
  <div class="item item3">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scroll the simplest solution would be to create a separate container for each view. Then make the overall container (`body`) a flex container in row direction.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

.flexbox {
  flex: 0 0 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="item item1">4</div>
  <div class="item item2">5</div>
  <div class="item item3">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, My earlier approach was the same as mentioned now. The items count is dynamic and I am using angular ng-repeat to render the HTML for all components. So this approach giving some performance issues because of some other functionalities which must work with the layouts. Can you help me with the CSS Grid approach?

Comment: My approach with CSS Grid would be similar to flex. I'm not entirely clear on the problem. Maybe you could provide more details.

Comment: You see the image in my question,I have updated it, right! At first items[1,2,3] will be displayed in the viewport, where item[1] will occupy 100% width and others will occupy only 50% width. When I scroll, items[4,5,6] will come into view from rtl fashion(To achieve this, I need horizontal scroll). I get an array of items like, items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]. And I use angular 1. So, I render the Html content like `<div class="flexbox"> <div class="item" ng-class="item.class" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.text}}</div>` </div>` . So I can not have separate container for each view.

Answer (score 0):

The main trick is to add `grid-auto-flow: column;` to your container's display grid css styles.

**For Example**

```css
.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20rem, 20rem));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try to add class with this style to the element that you want to have horizontal scroll on it

```
display: block;
width: 99%;
overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: I am asking for `display: flex;` or `display: grid;`, I knew what you said will work. But, I want to maintain the layout also with items inside the container. Did you check the code pens?